# JSON object with muliple key names for a single value. And how do I read that?

Tags: javascript, json, object, javascript-objects

I run into with such an object with strange key.

```
const obj = {
formValues: {
'TOTAL;_null_;_null_;3;_null_': "100"
'billing;_null_;_null_;1;_null_': "Y"
'billing;_null_;_null_;2;_null_': "Y"
'billing;_null_;_null_;3;_null_': "Y"
}
}
```

Is that possible to parse it some how, to be able to grab that "100" value by using only "TOTAL" key word?

```
obj.formValues['TOTAL'] // gives an error
```

Did you see something like that? Then, can you explain why this was made so?
(It's not how I'm tring to use an object, I just found it and trying to understand why it looks so)

Comment: please add a valid object.

Comment: this is not valid json

Comment: It should be `obj ["TOTAL;_null_;_null_;3;_null_"]` (assuming you forgot to add `""` around your keys in the object literal) But, it should not throw an error. It will just return undefeind

Comment: @adiga, Yes. BTW, the same problem

Comment: `obj.formValues['TOTAL;_null_;_null_;3;_null_']`…?!

Comment: What do you mean *same problem*? Do you know the full key name before hand? Do you want to get the value from the key which STARTS WITH `'TOTAL'`? What error does it throw?

Comment: @adiga, I'm trying to grab that value by using a single key, is that possbile to parse it some how? In my case, it is TOTAL key.

Comment: There is no `'TOTAL'` key in your object. There is a key called `'TOTAL;_null_;_null_;3;_null_'`.

Comment: @TorenDubashit - Objects have only a single key for a property, it's impossible for a JavaScript object to have multiple keys for the same property. I've updated my community wiki answer below to show how to find a property with `TOTAL` in it and use that property's actual name.

Comment: Your basic mistake is thinking that there are "multiple" keys. There aren't. Each value only has one key, it's just that that key is pretty long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I run into with such an object with mupliple key names for one field.

Objects have only a single key for a property, it's impossible for a JavaScript object to have multiple keys for the same property. (It's possible to make a property an alias for another one, but that's different.)

In a comment you've said:

> I'm trying to grab that value by using a single key, is that possbile to parse it some how? In my case, it is TOTAL key.

You can do that by finding the actual property name, then using brackets notation to get the property value:

```
const name = Object.keys(obj.formValues).find(name => name.includes("TOTAL"));
if (name) {
    console.log(obj.formValues[name]); // "100"
}
```

**But**, there could be more than one property with `TOTAL` in the name, in which case you can't be sure which one you'd get. (Object properties do have an order now, but for properties with the kind of names in your object the order depends on the order in which the properties were created, which isn't something you should rely on.)

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {
    formValues: {
        "TOTAL;_null_;_null_;3;_null_": "100",
        "billing;_null_;_null_;1;_null_": "Y",
        "billing;_null_;_null_;2;_null_": "Y",
        "billing;_null_;_null_;3;_null_": "Y"
    }
};
const name = Object.keys(obj.formValues).find(name => name.includes("TOTAL"));
if (name) {
    console.log(obj.formValues[name]); // "100"
}
```

Or you could use `Object.entries` to get the name and value at the same time (but it involves creating a bunch of temporary arrays [JavaScript engines are really fast at doing that, though]):

```js
const obj = {
    formValues: {
        "TOTAL;_null_;_null_;3;_null_": "100",
        "billing;_null_;_null_;1;_null_": "Y",
        "billing;_null_;_null_;2;_null_": "Y",
        "billing;_null_;_null_;3;_null_": "Y"
    }
};
const property = Object.entries(obj.formValues).find(([name]) => name.includes("TOTAL"));
if (property) {
    const [name, value] = property;
    console.log(`Name is ${name}, value is ${value}`);
}
```